# How to avoid calling GetComponent() in OnTriggerEnter()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Simple question here..

I just want to know if there is a way to avoid calling `GetComponent<Script>()` inside `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`? i'm trying to avoid doing this since I know that GetComponent is slow.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Tile tile = other.GetComponent<Tile>();
    if (tile.colorIndex == GameManager.Instance.currentTargetColorIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably not worth it unless this method is firing on many objects in a single frame.

But, you could do it by caching the Tile objects in a dictionary and index them with `Collider.gameObject.GetInstanceID()`:

---

In some script where every instance of the script running `OnTriggerEnter` can access (such as a Game Manager):

```
public Dictionary<int, Tile> tileCache;

// ...

// Initializing:
tileCache = new Dictionary<int, Tile>();
```

Example use:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    int tileCacheIndex = other.gameObject.GetInstanceID();
    Tile tile;

    if (GameManager._instance.tileCache.ContainsKey(tileCacheIndex)) 
    {
        tile = GameManager._instance.tileCache[tileCacheIndex];
    }
    else 
    {
        tile = other.GetComponent<Tile>();
        GameManager._instance.tileCache[tileCacheIndex] = tile;
    }

    if (tile.colorIndex == GameManager.Instance.currentTargetColorIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit!");
    }
}
```

Because you're using the gameObject's instance ID, you could do something like pre-load the tile cache in each Tile's Start. The index would just be `gameObject.GetInstanceID()`, no calls to `GetComponent` necessary there.

Comment: You can also use the Collider as the key.

Comment: Well that's exactly what i'm looking for! thank you very much

Comment: It could be worth checking that GetInstanceID is indeed faster than GetComponent.

Comment: Good point, if GetInstanceID isn't meaningfully faster than Get Component, perhaps it would be best to use `other.gameObject` as the index, and make the dictionary use `GameObject` keys.

Comment: as Iggy mentioned, you could use the collider as key, no need to GetInstanceId then, however the cost of collision itself is quite high, I don't think GetComponent on collison is all that bad